Texture paint is not exported in gltf model
I have a model with texture painting with it. I want to export it and i checked the texture configuration in the export. I also saved my image texture in the same file. But why when i try to import my model to three js the texture isn't exported?




Do you need to add a light source to your ThreeJS render?  Maybe it's black because there is no light shining on it.
